# Is mongodb preinstalled in ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, mongodb

I just found mongodb is already installed on my ubuntu 18.04. I wonder where did it come from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not preinstalled in ubuntu you must've installed it accidentally or would've installed it along another package.